# in featuretools, How to Custom Primitives of 2 columns?

Tags: python, featuretools

I created Custom Primitives like below.

```
class Correlate(TransformPrimitive):
name = 'correlate'
input_types = [Numeric,Numeric]
return_type = Numeric
commutative = True
compatibility = [Library.PANDAS, Library.DASK, Library.KOALAS]

def get_function(self):
    def correlate(column1,column2):
        return np.correlate(column1,column2,"same")
    
    return correlate
```

Then I checked the calculation like below just in case.

```
np.correlate(feature_matrix["alcohol"], feature_matrix["chlorides"],mode="same")
```

However above function result and below function result were difference.

Do you know why those are difference?

If my code is wrong basically, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the question! You can create a custom primitive with a fixed argument to calculate that kind of correlation by using the `TransformPrimitive` as a base class. I will go through an example using this data.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [0.40168819, 0.0857946],
    [0.06268886, 0.27811651],
    [0.16931269, 0.96509497],
    [0.15123022, 0.80546244],
    [0.58610794, 0.56928692],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=list('ab'))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df
```

```
index         a         b
    0  0.401688  0.085795
    1  0.062689  0.278117
    2  0.169313  0.965095
    3  0.151230  0.805462
    4  0.586108  0.569287
```

The function `np.correlate` is a transform when the parameter `mode=same`, so define a custom primitive by using the `TransformPrimitive` as a base class.

```py
from featuretools.primitives import TransformPrimitive
from featuretools.variable_types import Numeric
import numpy as np


class Correlate(TransformPrimitive):
    name = 'correlate'
    input_types = [Numeric, Numeric]
    return_type = Numeric

    def get_function(self):
        def correlate(a, b):
            return np.correlate(a, b, mode='same')

        return correlate
```

The DFS call requires the data to be structured into an `EntitySet`, then you can use the custom primitive.

```py
import featuretools as ft

es = ft.EntitySet()

es.entity_from_dataframe(
    entity_id='data',
    dataframe=df,
    index='index',
)

fm, fd = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity='data',
    trans_primitives=[Correlate],
    max_depth=1,
)

fm[['CORRELATE(a, b)']]
```

```
       CORRELATE(a, b)
index                 
0             0.534548
1             0.394685
2             0.670774
3             0.670506
4             0.622236
```

You should get the same values between the feature matrix and `np.correlate`.

```py
actual = fm['CORRELATE(a, b)'].values
expected = np.correlate(df['a'], df['b'], mode='same')
np.testing.assert_array_equal(actual, expected)
```

You can learn more about defining [simple custom primitives](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/getting_started/primitives.html#Simple-Custom-Primitives) and [advanced custom primitives](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/guides/advanced_custom_primitives.html#Advanced-Custom-Primitives-Guide) in the linked pages. Let me know if you found this helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. However, I am using mode="same" as an argument to the correlate function.
Therefore, I think I should use TransformPrimitive, what do you think?
Or is it not possible to include an argument?

ex)
 In: np.correlate(df["a"],df["b"],mode=same")
Out:array([0.53454827, 0.39468522, 0.67077416, 0.67050648, 0.62223556])

Comment: Ah, thanks for point that out! Yes, that's correct. In that case, you would use `TransformPrimitive`. Transform and aggregation primitives do support primitive arguments, but in this specific use case, `mode=same` seems like the only valid transform parameter that returns a vector of the same size. I updated my answer to reflect this specific use case. Let me know if you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation. It was very helpful.
I didn't see any examples of using two features in the documentation, so I learned a lot from this.
Thank you.